# Advice on MongoDB Database Structure

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I am beginner to MongoDB and I have `Photo`, `Video` ,`Friend` and `User` collection in mongoDB.

I am implementing search by name functionality, where i need to display user with his number of friends, number of photos and number of videos.

Right now, what i do is i execute find query on `user` collection and get user objects/documents.

Then i execute `for loop` through search result and for each user i get number of friends, photos and videos using individual queries as MongoDB doesn't support join.

To get rid of this `for loop` i am planning to embed friend id, photo id and video id into user object/document as below

```
@Document
Class User {

   List<String> friendIds;

   List<String> phtotIds;

   List<String> videoIds;
}
```

Is this correct way or is there any better solution?

Please guide.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [References vs embeds in MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950099/references-vs-embeds-in-mongodb)

Comment: Found an even better duplicate: [MongoDB relationships: embed or reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373198/mongodb-relationships-embed-or-reference/)

Comment: Here are the according docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/